# AFNetworking block and feed

Tags: ios, uitableview, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking

Okay I have another question, tonight, using AFNetworking, i parse my JSON Stream, an add object an MutableArray, when i insert try to print the array outside of the success block, it says null, but inside of this block it works, so how can i pass the _listOfNewsArray into the mainthread ?

This is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bgWhitelight" ofType:@"png"];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]];

NSURLRequest *newsRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://aXXXXXXXXXXXipt/beta.php"]];

AFJSONRequestOperation *newsJSONRequest = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:newsRequest success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
{
    NSArray *newsArray = [JSON objectForKey:@"news"];
    _listOfNews = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSDictionary *oneNews in newsArray) {

        CCENews *currentNews = [[CCENews alloc]init];
        currentNews.title = [oneNews objectForKey:@"title"];
        currentNews.content = [oneNews objectForKey:@"content"];
        currentNews.category = [currentNews getHiResCategoryPicture:[oneNews objectForKey:@"category"]];
        currentNews.date = [oneNews objectForKey:@"date"];
        currentNews.imageURL = [oneNews objectForKey:@"pictureurl"];

        [_listOfNews addObject:currentNews];
    }
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];

[newsJSONRequest start];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, i found the solution, just using self.listOfNews, just had to think about it !-

Answer (score 0):

Move the creation of *listOfNews out of the block and into viewDidLoad, or make the ivar a block variable (*_block NSM....). I prefer the first solution.